# How to print corresponding summary words like mean, max in ggplot R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

[image]

Here is my code to generate this figure....

```
ggplot(dataS, aes(x = property_name, y = val_int,fill=property_name)) +
  geom_boxplot()+ylim(0,4.5)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = means, aes(label =  means$val_int, y = 3.5))+
  geom_text(data = sds, aes(label =  sds$val_int, y =  3.75))+
  geom_text(data = maxs, aes(label =  maxs$val_int, y =  4))+
  geom_text(data = mins, aes(label =  mins$val_int, y =  3.25))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1,vjust=1))
```

I wan to write down it like....max 9816 
                               sd 1810 and so on.....how do I do that?

Comment: It would help a lot if you broke down your code into multiple lines.

Comment: Maybe `geom_text(data = means, aes(label =  paste("Mean:", means$val_int), y = 3.5))`?

Comment: I tried breaking it down ....for some reason it's not taking it..
`ggplot(dataS, aes(x = property_name, y = val_int,fill=property_name)) + geom_boxplot()+ylim(0,4.5)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = means, aes(label =  means$val_int, y = 3.5))+
  geom_text(data = sds, aes(label =  sds$val_int, y =  3.75))+
  geom_text(data = maxs, aes(label =  maxs$val_int, y =  4))+
  geom_text(data = mins, aes(label =  mins$val_int, y =  3.25))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1,vjust=1))`

Comment: @Lyngbakr awesome....buddy ....you are just great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer:

```
ggplot(dataS, aes(x = property_name, y = val_int,fill=property_name)) +
  geom_boxplot()+ylim(0,4.5)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = means, aes(label =  paste("Mean:", means$val_int), y = 3.5))+
  geom_text(data = sds, aes(label =  paste("SD:", sds$val_int), y =  3.75))+
  geom_text(data = maxs, aes(label =  paste("Max:", maxs$val_int), y =  4))+
  geom_text(data = mins, aes(label =  paste("Min:", mins$val_int), y =  3.25))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1,vjust=1))
```